# how to properly implement a Bootstrap tooltip?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement a Bootstrap tooltip. To a form I've added:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-trigger="click" title="My text..."><%=image_tag('help.png')%></a>
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
  })
</script>
```

It works in that clicking the image displays "My text". Two problems arise though:

- Upon clicking help.png, `#` is added to the page's url and the page automatically scrolls all the way to the top of the page.
- After clicking help.png, the image has a dotted frame around it: [image]

How to solve this?

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors in the debug console ?

Comment: You should not add a tooltip to `a` element but rather a `span`

Comment: Check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ad047zkz/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Replacing it with `span` solved it. Will you add it as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

The tooltip feature from Bootstrap can be added to any HTML that features the data attribute and title. So with that in mind you can probably update the 'a' tag to a 'span' instead.

The dotted frame I believe is the focus of the click. Adding CSS such as the following should resolve the issue:

```
.example:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the 1st issue: # added to your page URL, you can use "javascript:void(0);"

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-trigger="click" title="My text..."><%=image_tag('help.png')%></a>
```

It will not append # in the page URI.